# Jquery at wordpress admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, admin

I tried to add simple jquery functionality at the admin area to a simple widget I am develpoing such as:

`jQuery("$id").show()` and `jQuery("$id").hide()`

functions, but they are not working.

Can anyone tell me how to use jquery at WP admin area?

Answer (score 0):

Try `jQuery("#\\$id").show();` and `jQuery("#\\$id").hide();`

Comment: @m90 if the `id` of the element is `$id` for escaping the special chracters, use two backslashes. check out [How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation? on the jQuery FAQ][1]: [1]:http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How%5Fdo%5FI%5Fselect%5Fan%5Felement%5Fby%5Fan%5FID%5Fthat%5Fhas%5Fcharacters%5Fused%5Fin%5FCSS%5Fnotation.3F

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I it seems I made a made a mistake in my question, jquery selector should be jQuery("#id") and not jQuery("id"), sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

There a two possible issues here. First one might be that you are selecting the `ID`s in a strange way. Usually yo would select an element by ID in jQuery just like in CSS with the `#`-prefix, like: `$('#id').show()` or `$('#id').hide()`. In case you know this and are just storing a CSS selector in `$id` you are already fine.

Second thing that many people struggle with is that your jQuery has to wait for the DOM to be ready before it can actually take effect (if it gets executed before the DOM is ready all the selections will be empty). To get this done you usually wrap your code in a `$(document).ready`-Listener:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#id').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This way all the code inside the handler function will wait until the DOM is ready before it gets executed.

On a side note: as you mentioned `show()` and `hide()` as your examples you might also be interested in `toggle()`: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: At wordpress administration panel this doesn't work, working fine at the front end but not at the admin panel.

Comment: The problem is that every element from the widget must have a class not an ID . Seems that wordpress is doing some kind of magic and block your script doing anything, and they are doing it right because what about having 2 same widgets on the sidebar ? You will have ids with same name and that's not good.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element with id like

```
<div id="myId"></div>
```

then you can select your div as

```
jQuery("#myId").show();
```